# Checking if post is posted via application Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If I have post-id, how can I check if that post is posted via some application or not? I've tried with ["application"] but it does not work.

I have researched and could not find the answer. There is not a thread like here so I guessed I can create it.

Sorry If I have missearched, thank you.

P.s. I know how to get all the posts and how to access every single one of them, but not how to check if it's from the app or not.

Comment: What kind of posts - belonging to a user or a page? When it comes to user posts, this might simply be a privacy issue.

Comment: Both. I need for user page and for a page also.

Comment: Using the `application` field works fine for me for posts on a page as well as on a user profile.

Comment: I can access the id field, but not application, it says, "undefined index", can you please show me a code, or even a pseudo.

Comment: Since API v2.4, you get only a couple of default fields, if you want more than that, you need to explicitly ask for those fields. Go read the documentation chapter on basic API usage, it is explained in there.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I got it now.